# adding event to an element using setAttribute

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I am creating multiple elements of the same kind using JavaScript. I want to add an `onclick` event to the element. My code so far:

```
for(let i=0;i<localStorage.length;i++)
{
var rem=document.createElement("button");
rem.innerHTML='<i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
rem.setAttribute('background-color','white');
rem.setAttribute('id',localStorage.key(i));
rem.setAttribute('class','delbuttons');
rem.setAttribute('onclick','del(e)');
document.body.appendChild(rem);
}
```

My `del` function:

```
function del(event) {
  var id = event.target.getAttribute('id'); 
  localStorage.removeItem(id);
  window.location.reload();
}
```

But this does not work. What is going wrong?

Comment: Where is that function defined? Functions called from inline js needs to be in global scope. Also why use setAttribute, you can set the property directly or use addEventListener

Comment: it's not just for one element. Im creating multiple buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
 rem.onclick = function(e) {del(e);};
```

Comment: > Uncaught SyntaxError: Function statements require a function name.

Comment: `setAttribute('onlick',del(e))` That would execute the function immediately and not set it to execute on click. Also attributes are strings so you cant use a function reference as it would be coerced to a string which wouldnt work correctly

Answer (score 2):

When using html event attributes any variable or function used in it needs to be in global scope for it to be accessible. Meaning not defined in some function or object. Also in your example you passed `e` to the function but there is not variable named `e` in your example. If you meant to pass in the `event` object then you should use `event` not `e`:

```
rem.setAttribute('onclick','del(event)');
```

But there is no real reason to use `setAttribute` here, you can more readily set the `onclick` property or use `addEventListener`. The latter being better as you can use it to setup multiple event handlers for the same event. You also dont have to explicitly pass in the `event` object

```
rem,onclick = del;
//or
rem.addEventListener('click',del);
```

Because you have many elements you could also just use a [delegated event listener](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) so you dont have to explicitly set an event for every single element. You just set one on a common static parent element

```
document.addEventListener('click',function(event){
  //event.target is the element firing the ev4nt
  if(evrnt.target.classLidt.contains('delbuttons')){
    /* your code here */
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare a function, and then you can attach that function to a node with click or any other event, please find below code snippet:

```js
function del() {
  var id = event.target.getAttribute('id'); 
  localStorage.removeItem(id);
  window.location.reload();
}
```

```html
var rem=document.createElement("button");
rem.innerHTML='<i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
rem.setAttribute('background-color','white');
rem.setAttribute('id',localStorage.key(i));
rem.setAttribute('class','delbuttons');
rem.onclick = del;
document.body.appendChild(rem);
```

Comment: You are executing the function immediately, not setting a reference. You also didnt pass in the `event` obj

Comment: We can declare a function, but it will execute once it is attached to a node, and the attached event is triggered

Comment: Yes if you set a function reference but that is not what you are doing. `del()` is immediately executing the function not using it as a reference, eg `rem.onclick = del;` is, notice there are no `()`

Comment: Correct, the idea was to provide solution based on query asked, it was not intended to add rem.onclick = del(), rather rem.onclick = del, appreciate your efforts, thanks for the update, please check now